# How to extract data from file and assign each data to each variables on python?

Tags: python, file, extract

So i wannna know the solution from my question. I already tried this

```
import re


username = ""
password = ""
full_name = ""
birth_date = ""
phone_number = ""
address = ""


with open("file2.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

lines = contents.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    if ": " in line:
        key, value = re.split(":\s*", line)
        
        if key == "Username":
            username = value
        elif key == "Password":
            password = value
        elif key == "Nama Lengkap":
            full_name = value
        elif key == "Tanggal Lahir":
            birth_date = value
        elif key == "Nomor HP":
            phone_number = value
        elif key == "Alamat":
            address = value

print(username)
print(password)
print(full_name)
print(birth_date)
print(phone_number)
print(address)
```

But the output is not what i expected. The username and password value not appearing, here when i run it

```
kjdaskd
10-20-1000
+218112301231
dsajh
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It just printing 2 line of blank or whitespace. How to solve this?

This is inside file2.txt

```
Username : dsadj
Password : 12345
Nama Lengkap: kjdaskd
Tanggal Lahir: 10-20-1000
Nomor HP: +218112301231
Alamat: dsajh
```

This is the output that i expect:

```
dsadj
12345
kjdaskd
10-20-1000
+218112301231
dsajh
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty lines come from your variables `username` and `password` not being updated from their initial empty string.

Due to the extra whitespace in your source file, your equality checks fail since you're testing `if "Username " == "Username":` which is never true (notice the extra whitespace).

Change it to this to allow zero or more whitespace before the colon:

```
key, value = re.split("\s*:\s*", line)
#                      ^^^
```

Outputs:

```
dsadj
12345
kjdaskd
10-20-1000
+218112301231
dsajh
```

Alternatively, change your source file to always have no white-space before colons - it will have the same effect. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In file2.txt you have "Username " and "Password " with space in the end before ":". So "Username " != "Username" and "Password " != "Password"